# Error on macOS startup - "The application can't be opened."

Tags: macos, ventura

Recently, I updated my Apple ID email address, and I logged out and back into my Apple account within the settings on my 2018 mac Mini (see info below). Now, when restarting, I consistently get an error message with a `-50` error code. I've narrowed the culprit down to either tmpNote or Amphetamine (both downloaded from the App store).

[image: error message]

If I remove the applications (and supposedly all residual files) using AppCleaner, I don't get the error on startup. Unfortunately, when reinstalling these apps, the error reappears. I'd like to use these apps and try to find some sort of fix without fully reformatting my computer. Is there some sort of system link or file that I should be looking to remove?

- 2018 mac Mini
- Ventura 13.0.1

**Update**

I've narrowed down the problematic application to tmpNote specifically and the functionality related to allowing applications to run in the background. When this setting is turned on, I get the error message above.

[image: allow in the background settings]

Comment: Are there updates to Amphetamine and tmpNote? Available?

Comment: @IconDaemon I checked on that also, to be sure. There were no updates available for either application unfortunately.

Comment: Try this diagnostic step: while the computer is running, quit both apps and restart them; see which one gives the error message.

Comment: I've discovered the sole app with the issue is tmpNote (which is downloaded from the App store). Specifically, there is a setting to **Allow in the Background** which seems to be causing issues. I've updated the main question with an image showing the settings for this section.

Answer (score 1):

After speaking directly with Apple support, I performed a Safe Boot with the orphaned entry toggled **ON**. I'm not sure exactly what mechanism within the Safe Boot process helped, but it seemed to purge the application's phantom listing. When rebooting into a normal user session, I did not receive the error message and the orphaned entry was no longer listed.

I was able to reinstall the application and it appears that it registered as a fresh background service and functions properly now.